# Enforce password change every 90 days (3 months)

Tags: password

I am currently building an intranet for a client and one of their requirements is that staff must update their passwords every 90 days.

I assume I would need to build a plugin for this, but what would be best to way to approach this? I was hoping it might work whereby this was set 90 days after the last password change, rather than a fixed date for every user.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$date90DaysAgo = (new \DateTime())->modify('90 days ago')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
foreach(\craft\elements\User::find()->lastPasswordChangeDate('<='.$date90DaysAgo)->all() as $user){
    Craft::$app->getUsers()->sendPasswordResetEmail($user);
    $user->newPassword = // generate some temp password, so the user can't login with his/her anymore
    $user->setScenario(User::SCENARIO_PASSWORD);
    Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($user);
}
```

get the date 90 days ago, find all users where `lastPasswordChangeDate` is smaller than this date, send them a new password reset email and change their password to something else, so they can't login anymore.

Comment: Thanks for this Robin. Excuse my nativity but aside from creating this in a plugin how/what do I need to do to get this to run?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I am not sure how this code would run? Or how to make it run?
I assume I would need to create it as a plugin but then when/how does it go through and reset the passwords for those that have expired?

Comment: Same question again, I have no idea what you mean... You need to create a module or a plugin and copy the code there. You could use a very easy and nasty solution and just copy it into your init function so it's executed in every request or you create a route with a controller to access it via cronjob. Do you want to know what it does exactly or how to create a controller or route or what?